# How to retrieve specific document id on itemclickviewlistener from firebase

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

```
fgboys.whereEqualTo("date", date)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(final QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                             String data="";


                            if(tvDate.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                                Toast.makeText(ProgramToProgram.this, "Please select date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            else{

                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                    PID = documentSnapshot.getId().toString().trim();
                                    String temp = documentSnapshot.get("session").toString();



                                    data = "\nPID: "+ PID +"\n" + "session: "+ temp+"\n";

                                    arrayList.add(data);
                                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                }
```

i want to retrieve the document id of that specific document i click on

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        fgboys.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {


                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        pid = documentSnapshot.getId().toString().trim();
                    }
 Toast.makeText(ProgramToProgram.this, " pid:" + pid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
    }
});
```

This is what i have tried but on clicking any item it is returning only one specific id

so my database structure is like : Collection - ProgramDetails and under this collection i have many documents which have auto generated id's and this document id is what i want

fgboys is where i have called the collection ProgramDetails

Comment: Hi, can you show a bit more of code, do you have this in an adapter?

Comment: no, i do not have this in an adapter

Comment: If you don't have an adapter, how are you displaying the data in the `ListView`?

Comment: i have stored the data in an array list and i am using an array adapter to display the data in a listview

Comment: Please post your database structure and which value you want

Comment: so my database structure is like : Collection - ProgramDetails and under this collection i have many documents which have auto generated id's and this document id is what i want

Comment: fgboys is where i have called the collection ProgramDetails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying only one database location(**fgboys**) on every item click, Plus value of variable **pid** is overwritten in for loop, so everytime you will get id of last document in list.

you can store list of documentId in separate list and retrieve id of clicked list item.

```
 private List<String> docIds=new ArrayList<>(); //declare id list
        fgboys.whereEqualTo("date", date)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {




                        if(tvDate.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(ProgramToProgram.this, "Please select date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        else{
                            docIds.clear();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                String data="";
                                PID = documentSnapshot.getId().toString().trim();
                                docIds.add(PID);
                                String temp = documentSnapshot.get("session").toString();



                                data = "\nPID: "+ PID +"\n" + "session: "+ temp+"\n";

                                arrayList.add(data);
                                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            }

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


       pid=docIds.get(position);
 Toast.makeText(ProgramToProgram.this, " pid:" + pid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: yes, that is right ... so how do i get id of the document i am clickin on?

Comment: I am using an array adapter

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Yes but what data you are passing in adapter

Comment: i am passing an arraylist

Comment: I'm asking about database query for array list of adapter

Comment: is that working for you? data  is not duplicated for other items in list?

Comment: YES! that is perfect, thank you so much nehal 'god'hasara!!

Comment: can you help me out with this question , i have but the link :            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185933/how-to-query-and-store-data-in-an-arraylist-from-firestore?noredirect=1#comment106454478_60185933